# How to create FB Album on Android using GraphApi

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to create a FB album using GraphApi on an Android App, below is my code snippet for accomplishing this.

```
GraphRequest createAlbum = new GraphRequest();                                
createAlbum.setAccessToken(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
createAlbum.setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
Bundle createAlbumParams = new Bundle();
createAlbumParams.putString("name", "Test_Album");
createAlbumParams.putString("message", "Test_Album_Description");
createAlbum.setParameters(createAlbumParams);
createAlbum.setGraphPath(fbUserId + "/albums");
// createAlbum.setGraphPath("me/albums");
    createAlbum.setCallback(new GraphRequest.Callback() {
         public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
         }
    });
createAlbum.executeAsync();
```

The the returned AccessToken has "publish_actions" permission set. The fbUserId is a valid FB userId that was returned when I used a GET method on the "graph.facebook.com/me" path.

I logged in to my FB account via the following code:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mFbCallbackManager, mFbLoginCallback);
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(mActivity,Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
```

I always get authentication error in the GraphResponse object in the GraphRequest.Callback as shown below:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 10, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#10) Application does not have permission for this action}}
```

After poking around on the FB Developers site, I've realized that the "publish_actions" permission has to be granted to my App by the FB review, but I can't submit my App for review, since FB features are not implemented/working yet. There was an option to create a Test App for my App, which I assumed would have the "publish_actions" granted to it without having to have the App reviewed by FB. The Test App has a different facebook_app_id, which I changed in my Android App. I am still getting the same error.

How do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don’t need to submit for review while you are developing – any user with a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) can be asked for any permission *without* prior review.

And creating albums requires the `user_photos` permission.

Comment: you answer lead me to do some more experimentation. I can't specify "user_photos" permission in the logInWithPublishPermissions(), nor can I specify loginWithReadPermissions() before loginWithPublishPermissions() - i.e. 2 back to back calls. I ended up calling logInWithReadPermissions("user_photos") and in the onActivityResult() would call logInWithPublishPermissions("publish_actions").